# Unable to import date data into App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

[appmaker] I'm trying to import data from related data in google sheets into an App Maker. I created the fields by importing them from sheets. The date field defaulted to a time stamp but my data only uses the date, so I changed the fields to date only but the import keeps failing because App maker is still expecting a time stamp.  Any ideas?

So the images show how I have set up the data model for this data.  It is set up as a 'Date' . But it keeps getting rejected.

[Details from App Maker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V0iK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample spreadsheet and a sample AppMaker app to try and replicate your issue. It works perfectly well for me. To have perfect sync, you might need to re-check these two points.

1. Are you sure you used "Date" SQL Type in the AppMaker model's field like this?

[image]

2. Are you sure your spreadsheet's date column has the correct date format set like this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  The date field is set up correctly all the dates present themselves in the correct format and the SQL type is set correctly.  I am using a multiple sheet data model and trying to import using the method for related tables.  Did you import your headers or put them in manually?  I imported the headers first and then had to change the SQL type manually because it defaults to a timestamp, maybe I need to enter the date fields manually and remove the imported ones perhaps?  I just don't understand why it is not working.